# What is needed to be done to obtain the powers to become a Daemon Prince?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have been reading about the subject in Warhammer 40k, and I have raised a series of questions about the "transformation" suffered by a devotee of Chaos to become a Daemon Prince.

What are the requirements a devotee must fulfill, the "minimal" requirements for becoming a Daemon Prince? Is it a ritual?

If you can put the source of your answer and any additional information about the ritual and the requirements it will be nice.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like "a series of questions", as the questions are pretty connected, but it'd probably be clearer and less broad if you rewrote it so there's one main question asked concisely.

Comment: If Akira Toriyama becomes author for W40K, there would be a Super Mystic Daemon God Blue 3 transformation.

Comment: Quick answer: 1. You need to sacrifice A LOT - whole planets, systems etc. Eventually you have to sacrifice someone really significant. 2. No, there is no higher hierarchy, but obviously different princes have different level of power.

Comment: The rank above princes would be the Chaos Gods themselves.

Comment: okey i will edit this ^^ thansk for the comments guys.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins If memory serves in one version of the fluff, the Greater Daemons were actually higher 'rank' than the Daemon Princes, but there was no real path to go from Prince to Greater Daemon (the Greater Daemons being native warp denizens while Princes are humans who've been "blessed".  Not sure if that's current canon or not, it's been a few years.

Comment: @Paul - yes, I believe you're quite correct on that.

Comment: I dont think the answer to this has ever been fully clarified, but the closest example might be found in Storm of Iron (http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/storm-of-iron-ebook.html). The Warmaster leading the siege is mentioned as being festooned with Daemonic Gifts already (can't recall if it mentions what he did to get them), but *SPOILERS* at the end of the book after the fall of the Imperial Fortress and the stealing of a large amount of Space Marine geneseed, he is finally granted another gift (wings I think), is called a Daemon Prince and leaves for the Immaterium (Warp).

Comment: Unrelated, but I find that when writing "Greater Daemon" I start wanting to spell it "Graeter Daemon".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific set of rites or ritual you need to perform to ascend to Daemon Prince. The process is very unclear.

Each current Daemon Prince had to commit countless atrocities to even gain the attention of it's chosen Chaos god. There's usually some subconcious urge to complete a task or slay a specific foe, once this is accomplished, you would know that the reward is ascension.

The closest thing to an actual guide would be somthing like:

- Kill a lot of people
- Kill even more people
- Let everyone know you really like Khorne
- Kill even more people while letting them know you really like Khorne
- Start hearing Khornes voice in your head
- Receive blessings from Khorne, power, gifts(mutations / ability to shoot fireballs and such), weapons, armour, etc.
- Kill many thousands more people
- Live for centuries, all the while killing and talking about how great Khorne is
- Realize what it is you need to do to ascend... (kill this guy or blow up this planet)
- Do that thing
- Bingo! Now you have wings.

It's never specifically addressed in the fluff and I think this is very deliberate. Each Chaos Champion has to do somthing different if they wish to ascend, this leaves the Games Workshop and it's writers freedom to create different and unique stories for each prince.

---

Primarchs get special treatment, they just need to ask and a Chaos god will snap them up.

Comment: Some Source? :/

Comment: You miss the fact that there are branches to that tree (even notwithstanding that you only covered Khorne's path).  Along the way you're receiving various Chaos Gifts as well, and the end state for most Champions of Chaos is actually getting overloaded with them and becoming Spawn.  Or at least that's how it was in Realms of Chaos, #OldSchoolChaos

Comment: @Paul you're totally right, ending up Chaos Spawn in a possibility! But my Chaos Champion makes it all the way to daemonhood :). And in my mind _power_ covered gifts, but that might be amibigous, I'll add that in.

Comment: @Gawey I'm afraid I don't have any. This is just what I've learned in the past 9 or 10 years reading the fluff.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to a clearly laid out process to my knowledge is in the [Black Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Crusade_(role-playing_game)) corebook (which is not exactly official, especially now that FFG no longer has the license to continue publishing the RPG): essentially, you need to acquire enough favour with the gods (or god of your choice) while devoting yourself more and more to them and eventually they will reward your efforts with ascension (and if you fail or aren't strongwilled enough, you'll turn into chaos spawn instead).

In actuality, there's no defined process: it's entirely up to the whims of the dark gods (but, presumably, you still need to actually worship them and have sufficient willpower to survive the process), so you could genocide planet after planet in the name of Khorne and never ascend, or you could be a serf slaving away in a manufactorum, get fed up and punch your supervisor, only to find yourself ascended (the former is, naturally, much more likely than the latter).